# How do I retrieve Google Calendar Resources for my company using the PHP API client?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use this client library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

I see how to fetch calendars and events, but how does one fetch a company's calendar resources like meeting rooms?

Just to expand a little bit, I'm looking at trying to fetch things like this: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/#retrieving_calendar_resources

In their examples, I don't see the PHP library.  Is this not possible with the current client library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I can't.

"No, looks like that API is a GData one - this library is only for the newer JSON based ones."

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/206