# How do I retrieve Google Calendar Resources PHP API client?

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk

How fetch google calendar resource using php-client [I found same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925355/how-do-i-retrieve-google-calendar-resources-for-my-company-using-the-php-api-cli) , I did not get any help from answer.

Can there is get all resource from google calendar of my company using [download google admin sdk PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples)

I could not get any sample or method into this lib how to get all resources like rooms. There is any way to fetch resource from company google calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar.readonly']);
$client->setSubject('user@domain.com');
$directoryService = new \Google_Service_Directory($client);

$resources = $directoryService->resources_calendars->listResourcesCalendars('my_customer')->getItems();

var_dump($resources);
```